# Легальность использования интернет-справочников

Tags: авторские-права

Это всего лишь предположение, но...

В интернете есть, как, наверное, все знают, много справочников и прочих полезных вещей, очень помогающих писать код.

Но откуда эта информация берется на сайтах? Если из чьих-то книг, тогда эти сайты можно считать пиратскими? Куда выгоднее получить бесплатную информацию там, чем отдавать несколько десятков долларов только за одну книгу. Потому автор книг теряет хлеб. Я не прав? Кто знает - просветите, я совсем запутался.

Примеры таких справочников:

- [www.cppreference.com](http://www.cppreference.com)
- [www.cppstudio.com](http://www.cppstudio.com)

Comment: Приведите примеры "справочников", о которых вы говорите. Но вообще вопрос на тонкой грани у оффтопика, т. к. он скорее юридический, чем технический.

Comment: www.cppreference.com

Comment: www.cppstudio.com

Comment: @Anon_ch CC-BY-SA и GNU. Это вообще-то на сайте указано.  That means that you can use this site in almost any way you like, including mirroring, copying, translating, etc. All we would ask is to provide link back to cppreference.com so that people know where to get the most up-to-date content. In addition to that, any modified content should be released under a equivalent license so that everyone could benefit from the modified versions

Comment: Сайт разрешил, но ведь есть же и "исходные" авторы всей этой информации,их я и имел в виду

Comment: @Anon_ch это вики. Если такая информация была помещена, либо автор дал согласие, либо поместивший нарушил правила сайта. Если код создан поместившим - оно получает эту защиту, иначе код изначально должен был иметь такую лицензию ИЛИ  был сопровожден разрешением на публикацию от автора. Вообще, "там" это должен решать сам автор, являются ли его права нарушенными, это только у нас за автора решает дядя Вася (так и получается, что у нас театр обвиняется в нарушении авторского права на Пер Гюнта, хотя все до 1927 года - общественное достояние)

Comment: @Anon_ch в их законодательстве нарушение АП - это что-то делаемое _осознанно_. Если код был помещен нелегально, это было сделано вне ведения администрации, и они ничего не нарушают до тех пор пока автор не связался с ними. Если вы воспользовались  информацией с этого сайта, вы защищены от ответственности гарантией, данной администрацией (именно поэтому указание источников важно в том числе и при возникновении диспутов с третей стороной), однако обязаны исправить положение дел. Есть  так же условие "fair use" - например , академические использование авторских материалов, но это вопрос сложный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый сайт имеет свое соглашение, но как правило оно схоже с Cretive Commons. Существют пермиссивные солгашения,  , используемые такими сайтами или отдельными авторами: WTFPL (делай-все-что-ты-хочешь), CC0  и др. Естественно, любой код с  "открытыми" лицензиями  GPL и DFSL может приводиться свободно.  Вообще , по международному соглашению (которое Россия подписала но некоторые российские компании его отрицают), исходный код рассматривается так же как литературное произведение. Цитирование с целью обучения, цитирование, не нарушающее исходной лицензии и создание кода по мотивам цитируемого не является нарушением, хотя использование патентованных средств. алгоритмов и т.п. может вызвать проблемы (например, если вы находитесь в США и пытаетесь реализовать сжатие mp3)

Следует заметить, что код, не содержащий уникального\оригинального материала не может быть защищен копирайтом (аналогично абстрактному тексту на любом человеческом языке). Таким образом, обобщенные примеры, не содержащие ничего оригинального, не защищены ничем, кроме как закона , определяющих их принадлежность к  Public Domain - публичному достоянию. Принадлежность к публичному достоянию определяется каждой юрисдикцией по отдельности, и тем не менее, не отрицает авторского права, если такое существовало. "Обшие" примеры, могут не быть предметом авторского права, но и не являться Public domain, просто они не могут являться предметом регистрации ( степень общности так же зависит от юрисдикции, это часто является причиной диспутов).

В ряде стран код не может быть  предметом копирайта. В России алгоритм не может быть предметом копирайта, но конкретная реализация может подлежать  авторскому праву, НО не автоматом, а только при регистрации такового. В США  алгоритмы и шаблоны разработки являются предметом патента. Каждый сайт оперирует в законодательной среде страны, в которой он расположен, в остальном  будучи защищенным нейтральностью сети. Так что сайт не считается пиратским, если оперирует по закону своей страны и соблюдает Бернскую конвенцию (российское законодательство имеет превратный взгляд на данный момент)

Comment: *…обобщенные примеры, не содержанищие ничего оригинального, не защищены ничем.* — Защищены, это называется Public Domain.

Comment: @0andriy Public Domain это не определенная защита, это легальное определение интеллектуальной собственности, на которое копирайты, авторские права и т.п. не распростаняются или срок их действия истек.

Comment: Это не полное представление об общественном достоянии.

Comment: @0andriy Определение общественного достояния в каждой стране свое, и зачастую плохо применимо и исходному коду или к произвольному тексту (например, к тому, что я тут пишу). Иногда оно  настолько ограниченно , что требуются альтернативы для защита от создания "копилефта" через защиту их по соглашению с организацией Creative Commons.или аналогичных - WTFPL, Unilicense

Comment: @Swift следуя вашей логике, любой человек может объявить, что он автор, например Войны и Мира Толстого, который как известно находится в *public domain*

Comment: @Barmaley > Принадлежность к публичному достоянию ... не отрицает авторского права < что написано? Именно поэтому комментарий 0andriy, public domain - это то, на что авторство есть. Авторское право и копирайт (право на воспроизведение) вещи неэквивалентные.

Comment: @Barmaley  Если я скажу "мама мыла раму", это либо общая фраза, либо, в крайнем случае, общественное достояние - из букваря, а "мама ела "Раму", тут и торговая марка, и копирайт создателей рекламы.